# CAMBIAR 0 A NULL

Tags: mysql

Hola gente tengo esta consulta que me suma los campos , pero me trae valor 0 sino hay dato, hay alguna manera que en vez de 0 sea null o este vacio.????

```
SELECT
SUM(find_in_set('Normal', Condicion) >0 ) AS Normal,
SUM(find_in_set('Baliza Erronea', Condicion) >0 ) AS `Baliza Erronea`
FROM EXTINTORES
```

Comment: SELECT SUM().... FROM EXTINTORES WHERE campo IS NULL

Comment: no me estaria funcionando

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quieres un `NULL` en vez del `0`, puedes entonces usar la función [`NULLIF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif), que remplaza un valor por `NULL`  si éste coincide con otro:

```
SELECT NULLIF(SUM(find_in_set('Normal', Condicion) > 0 ), 0)        AS Normal,
       NULLIF(SUM(find_in_set('Baliza Erronea', Condicion) >0 ), 0) AS `Baliza Erronea`
       FROM EXTINTORES
```